# what I need to make mirage to constantly occur in sand desert?

Tags: science-based, deserts

I want to make a desert known to always generate mirages (I don’t mean it necessary occur during night though, only during a day is fine too, but if it possible for mirages to happen during the night, it is even better), even if the person is fine or not hungry or dehydrated to enhance the mirage due to their mind state, so whenever they look in any angle (eagle view or flying is optional, but it even better if mirage can generate even in that view) in there, it always generate some kind of mirage even just near the desert border, making it impossible to cross it without getting lost.

what do I need to make it possible for such kind of desert? Like the kind of surrounding, temperature, humidity, or the type of sand such as it is  more sparkly or reflective like a pile of small glass sand, etc.

I prefer it to be something that naturally occurs, not man made technology like a human using some kind of projection or simulation, and to make it clear, magic is out of this question.

I also dont want any hallucinogenic substance or drug to be part of it even if it naturally occurred, because I want it be a mirage.

feel free to correct my grammar and add the correct tag to this, since i dont know what tag is more appropriate for this.

Comment: I don't usually down-vote... but I don't believe you took the time to research what a mirage is. This question makes no sense. You want a mirage that can be seen from any angle (180° hemisphere around the center of the mirage)? At any time of day or night? That isn't how mirages work.

Comment: @JBH but i did mention it not necessary occur during night in first paragraph there, but if theres a solution for it to occur during night its even better, and i dont mean it show the same mirage even if they look elsewhere, but when they look around theres always some mirage generated.

Comment: @LiJun I know what you said - but you should take the time to review how mirages work.  They're an optical illusion that requires the viewer to be in daylight, on the ground, and a considerable distance from anything taller than a jackalope. You seem to be asking for a general solution. What, exactly and specifically, do you need the mirage to do?

Comment: @JBH i put it there just in case its possible hence "not necessary" and "optional", like who know maybe using moonlight or starlight can create mirage or something by adding certain materials/combination, or  theres  exist a solution that can work even in bird eye view.

Comment: You may find the wikipedia article on [mirages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirage) useful.

Comment: A mirage is not going to stop people from crossing a desert. mirages are famous for tricking people to traveling FURTHER into deserts, becasue they often look like water.

Comment: @John "making it impossible to cross it without getting lost"

Comment: @LiJun people quickly learn what mirages are, and stop being tricked by them. A mirage just can't do what you want it to do unless it is magic.

Comment: @John would it still like that, if all they see everywhere in that desert is mirage? literally no blank spot? because thats what i try to imply in my question there.

Comment: @LiJun that's physically impossible, the conditions that can create a mirage are pretty narrow. Mirages only work at long distances. with a specific temprature difference. Its just not possible on an earthlike planet.

Comment: @John i mean in long distance. but every where (long distance) or angle they look in that desert has mirage.

Answer (score 3):

**A Mirage is nothing special**

As other people already pointed out, a Mirage can happen everywhere as long as you have a clear field of View and heat.

[image]

This is a Mirage. The weird distortion you see on hot surfaces when looked at from a low angle is also a Mirage.

They happen when Hot air Refracts light rays, thus creating this distortion effect. So again, this happens everywhere you look.

Deserts are more famous for them because they just appear bigger duo to the flat landscape. But look hard enough and you could see them at your home.

**At night**

Since a Mirage needs two things, heat and light, one at night is less easy to get. But they are known to appear then too. You can only see them if there is a strong light source. Like the moon or fire.